# In how many ways may $5$ people sit in a row of five chairs if two of them refuse to sit next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I think I have a hard problem. The problem is:

In how many ways may $5$ people sit in a row of five chairs if two of them refuse to sit next to each other?

The hard part is the possibilities of them not sitting next to each other.

Comment: Subtract the number of arrangements in which they sit next to each other from the total number of seating arrangements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out the number of ways you can place those two people, and then add the other three.

For the first part, there are $ 6 $ pairs of seats not next to each other and $2 $ ways to place those two people in those two seats, so that's $ 12 $ ways to seat those two people

Then placing the other three can be done in $3!=6$ ways

Total: $12 \cdot 6=72$ ways to seat those 5 people

Comment: why 12? isn't it 8?

Comment: How is this a hint? With only the first paragraph it would've been a hint. Now it's a full solution, possibly with some details left to work out.

Comment: why is it 6 pairs sir @Bram28

Comment: @LeonzoEscolar If you label the chairs 1,2,3,4,5, the pairs are 1+3 , 1+4, 1+5, 2+4, 2+5, 3+5

Answer (score 1):

Note that

**A)** The ways for 5 people to sit in a row of five is $5!$.

**B)** The ways two of them are next to each other is $4\cdot2$ and for each case you have 3! ways for the Others, thus we have $8\cdot 3!$ forbidden configurations.

Therefore the number of ways in which 5 people can sit in a row of five chairs if two of them refuse to sit next to each other are given by $A-B$ that is

$$5!-8\cdot 3!=120-48=72$$

Comment: why is it 4.2? @gimusi

Comment: @LeonzoEscolar the position are 1-2 or 2-3 or 3-4 or 4-5 and for each we can Exchange, thus for rule of product we have 4*2. Then for each position you have 3! ways for the others.

Comment: @LeonzoEscolar If two people sit next to each other, the first person must be in one of the first four seats.  There are two ways to choose who sits on the left within the block.

Comment: @gimusi I got downvoted too ... maybe it's because we gave away the answer too quickly ...

Comment: @Bram28 I give +1 to restore!

Comment: @gimusi Thanks! :)

Comment: Maybe because the original question showed no attempt to solve.

Comment: Yes but in first version I gave only hints. I posted the full solution after it was given. So I don’t understand why.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** Not a different answer, but maybe a (slightly) different way to think about the problem:

To find the number of arrangements in which the feuding two sit together, consider arrangements
of four objects: this pair and the other three people, then permute the two in the pair. $2(4!) = 48.$

The number of arrangements without restriction is $5! =120.$

The answer is the difference of these two numbers, which is @gemusi's Answer. 
(+1)

I think this method is 'best' because it easily generalizes to $n \ge 3$ people.